# Jquery validate plugin change default message

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the default require message in Jquery validation plugin.  I have tried the following, but it still prints the default message:

```
$("#form1").validate({
        ignore: [],
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 200
            }
            message: {
                firstName:{
                    required: "Custom error message."
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I change my message into messages

```
 messages: {
             firstName:"Custom error message."
}
```

Comment: Not `message` its `messages`

Comment: still nor working

Comment: I updated @SaravananN

Comment: From your code custom message only show for required label, you should write custom message for all rules.

Comment: probably missing `,` after rules object and extra set of `});` and `}`

Comment: thank you i solve it  @SaravananN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#form1").validate({
    ignore: [],
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 200
        },
        messages: {
            firstName:{
                required: "Firstname required",
                minlength: "Min length is 2",
                maxlength: "Max length is 200",
            }
        }
    }
});
```